# Is Fortran's parameter statement similar to C/C++'s #define statement?

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I am new to Fortran, but it looks to me that Fortran's `parameter` is similar to using `#define` in C/C++.  Are they similar?  Are they used in the same ways?  I know `#define` is a preprocessor statement and I wasn't sure what similarities or differences this may cause `#define` to have with `parameter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define` is a pre-processor statement to define a macro. Macros are replaced by their value during a pre-processing step. Please note that pre-processor statements are not part of the Fortran standard. Not every compiler supports them.

A `parameter`, on the other hand, denotes a named constant (similar to the C construct `const`). Any variable type may be used to declare a constant. This constant is defined at compile-time:

```
integer, parameter :: i = 1
real, parameter    :: a = 1.
complex,parameter  :: z = (1., 1.)
```

Answer (score 6):

As covered in a lot of detail in the other answers, an object with the `parameter` attribute is a *named constant*.  This attribute can be specified in the declaration, such as in the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276134) given by Alexander Vogt or using the `parameter` statement.

If pre-processing is used as `#define`, such as

```
#define int_literal 1
```

then, as also covered elsewhere, there is text-level replacement at the pre-processing stage, and so we have what is then a *literal constant*.

Now, why does this distinction matter?  That is, is there any real difference between the two fragments

```
#define nx 100
real x(nx)
```

and

```
integer, parameter :: nx=100
real x(nx)
```

?

Not very much, one may think.  However, consider

```
integer, parameter :: hello(*) = [1,2,3]
type(some_type), parameter :: tp = some_type(4,5,6)
```

We will struggle to find suitable `#define`s that allow us to do whatever we want as though we had those named constants.  With those named constants we can have things like

```
print *, hello(2)-PRODUCT(hello(1::2)), tp%b   ! For b one of the components.
```

That is, named constants are data objects which can be manipulated in exotic ways much more than can be hoped with literal text replacement.

For true pathology, consider the silly example

```
#define x 2.1
print *, 1/x
```

and

```
integer, parameter :: x=2.1
print *, 1/x
```

---

For completeness, an example of a parameter statement is

```
integer i
parameter (i=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

`parameter` is more similar to the `const` declaration in C/C++. It is a constant expression.

To get preprocessor in Fortran, you might consider using .F extension or force C preprocessor on Fortran code

Answer (score 3):

A PARAMETER is indeed a constant value to which you give a name.

The #define preprocessor command has a much wider and powerful goal: it substitutes a string for another wherever it occurs in the text of the program. The substituted string can be any code fragment. This is a way to let the program modify itself (just before compilation).

For instance

```
#define Operator +
S= 1 Operator 2 Operator 3;
```

is equivalent to

```
S= 1 + 2 + 3;
```

which you can easily turn to

```
S= 1 - 5 * 2 - 5 * 3;
```

if that makes sense.

Admittedly, it is an old usage to define constant parameters via macros,

```
#define DAYS_PER_WEEK 5
#define PI 22/7
```

though the compiler has no conscience that they are parameters, they remain pure text. With this example, `1/PI` is `1/22/7` which evaluates to `1/154`, not `7/22`.

Comment: But `7/22` and `1/154` have the same value, so not a problem, right? :-)

Comment: @rici: mh, 154 can cause overflow on a 6 bits machine.